# Difference between various 955 electron tubes

Tags: amplifier, rf, ham-radio

From the operational point of view, is there a notable difference between the following electron tubes?

Jan 955

JRC 955

Jan 955 VT121

JHY 955 VT121

I'm asking broadly about the *main* points (e.g.: frequency range, grid voltage, capacitance and likes).
Taking into account the age of these parts and the difficulty to obtain datasheets, even a broad opinion based on some past experience will be welcome.

EDIT: There are the datasheets for the [RCA955](https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/9/955.pdf) tube and the [Tung Sol 955](https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/127/9/955.pdf) tube, which may or may not be related to the question.

Comment: You're asking us to compare 4 different datasheet (*all* the data in a datasheet is an aspect of operation, maybe aside from storage conditions), without linking to a single one! We've got no clairvoyant abilities, we can't answer this stuff without datasheets, either.

Comment: @Marcus These parts are more than 90 years old, so, I'm asking someone who has sufficient experience with these tubes.

Comment: they still have datasheets; someone who's worked with four clones of the same RCA tube will probably have to look this up, just as well, using these datasheets, or own measurements. Now, finding someone with a notebook that contains notes that go beyond datasheet-specified performance, that would sound slightly unlikely in this community, to be completely honest! As you noticed, *these things are 90 years old*; they're really rarely the subject of *electrical engineering* these days: I think you'd have more luck in a tube-related hobbyist forum, that's where the relevant experience would be.

Comment: @Marcus. Maybe, but this question is still related to electronics, and not against the rules of this site. Regarding the datasheets, I was unable to find one on the web.

Comment: Hm, but the problem is that you're asking for (notable) operational differences – in what operation? These are clones, so they'll be close, for some definition of close, to the reference RCA 995. Whether or not deviations make *any* difference depends on the way they're used – for example, in a feedback configuration, the actual gain isn't important, but in the same circuit some other detail might make a difference. You're really asking a bit overly unspecific here.

Comment: If you're just hoping to start a discussion about these, cool, but that *really* doesn't fit the scope of this very Q&A-focused site.

Comment: @Marcus. Please, don't impute intentions that are not mine. I'm asking a simple question to persons that have the experience required to give a reasonable answer to it, according to their past experience.

Comment: :) fair point! (I generally assume your intention to be good, anyways.) But that doesn't change the fact that you're asking for operational differences of components without datasheet, and without even specifying what "operation" means – that's too broad, in my humble opinion.

Comment: I'll edit my question according to your remarks.

Comment: thank you very much! I still find this very broad, but I think it helped a lot!

Comment: I think @MarcusMüller has a point, it's a little broad. I have some old RCA (and other) tube books which very likely cover the 955, but I doubt there is little difference. The 3 letters preceding 955 refer to the manufacturer or source. JAN = Joint Army-Navy; JRC = Japan Radio Company.

Answer (score 1):

the 955 tube is an acorn type developed by RCA and first appeared in 1935.The data sheet for the RCA 955 tube is available at the following site:
https://frank.pocnet.net › sheets › 955

Also just Google "955 vacuum tube" to find additional information. Also Wikipedia has a long article discussing the tube.

Comment: see my edit plz.